# Run time complexity for Reversal of array?

Tags: java, time-complexity

Why the run time complexity for this logic is O(N)? The number of iterations are only half here. Please explain!

```
for(int i = 0; i < validData.length / 2; i++)
{
    int temp = validData[i];
    validData[i] = validData[validData.length - i - 1];
    validData[validData.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

Comment: The complexity grows linearly with the number of elements.  If you double `N`, you double the the number of iterations.

Answer (score 4):

Big O notation is about order of magnitudes and how the complexity relates to the number of elements. `O(1/2 * n) == O(n)`

Comment: Actually, it isn't about "orders of magnitude".

Answer (score 4):

Time complexity falls into one of the [Time complexity categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) :

- constant (O(1))
- logarithmic (O(log(N)))
- linear (O(N))
- quadratic (O(N^2))
- cubic (O(N^3))
- etc...

`O(N)` is the general approximation of the complexity `O(N/2)` in your case because the `1/2` is regarded as a `constant` (especially considering high values for N).

Therefore the final complexity is said to be `linear` (depending only on the value of N: the final execution time grows linearly with N).

Answer (score 0):

We are interested in how the algorithm scales as the input size grows and constants do not affect its behavior on a very large scale, in theory.

Therefore even if you are going through half of the array `O(1/2 * n)` in your case, in theory its still `O(n)`.